# do the parens of a function call act like a grouping operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

do the parens of a function call act like a [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) ?

```
2 * (3 + 1) // 3 + 1 is evaluated first

'a'.concat('b'.concat('c')) // 'b'.concat('c') is evaluated first
```

Since `+` and `concat` are both semigroups meaning that they satisfy the associative property `x(yz) = (xy)z`, aren't the parens of the concat function call acting like the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) ?

Comment: Parentheses just override operator precedence, they don't control the order of execution.

Comment: Please refer to a [table such as this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for operator precedence. Grouping operator has higher precedence than function calls, but you're right that the parameters are evaluated before the actual call.

Comment: Since Javascript doesn't have lazy evaluation, it's not possible to call a function without first evaluating the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the grammar for function call arguments also leads to a grouping of the expressions.

But no, it does not control the execution order, the expressions are still evaluated outside-in and left-to-right. (The reference to the function is evaluated first, then the arguments, then the function is called).

Comment: you found the subtle wording I couldn't articulate